# Synonyms for "типа того"

Tags: синонимы

What are synonymous expressions for `типо того` (or is it *тип**а***) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`где-то так, навроде того (colloquial)`

When we're speaking about something measurable:

`примерно, приблизительно, около, плюс-минус`

In fact we have really a lot of such 'terms'

Answer (score 3):

It is

> типа того

, literally 'of this sort'. And it translates almost the same way in English: 'kind of', 'sort of'.

> Ты что, надумал покидать компанию?! What, are you thinking of leaving the company?!
>
> Ну, типа того... Well, kind of...

The phrase usually bears a hint of speaker holding something behind or a degree of uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

вроде (вроде бы , вроде как);
похоже (похоже на то);
может быть (все может быть);
возможно

Answer (score 1):

The synonyms of "типа+Genitive" (used mostly in colloquial speech) are **"вроде+Genitive"** (used both in colloquial speech and in written speech, but it is more formal than "типа") and **"наподобие+Genitive"** (used mostly in written speech, quite formal).

- Он правда это сказал?
- Да, что то типа того (Что-то вроде того, что-то наподобие того).

Answer (score 0):

**Что-то вроде того** could be used as well.